# How to convert a Dataset into an indexed dataset / association-of-associations given a column header?

Tags: dataset, associations, column

Given a dataset as such

[image: Input]

If `"letter"` is the header that is chosen, how do I convert it into an indexed dataset / association-of-associations?

i.e. How do I define `f` such that `f[dataset_,columnHeader_]` produces the following?

[image]

Please note `GroupBy` is close but fails as you are unable to use `Part` to work with the result to extract column data. eg:

```
data = {<|"letter" -> "a", "foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2|>, <|"letter" -> "b", "foo" -> 3, "bar" -> 4|>, <|"letter" -> "c", "foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 6|>};
dataDS = Dataset[data];
dataDSg= GroupBy[dataDS, Key["letter"]];
dataDSg[All, "foo"] (* <- produces an error *)
```

Where as data in the format of an association-of-association works fine

```
data2 = <|"a" -> <|"foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2|>, "b" -> <|"foo" -> 3, "bar" -> 4|>, "c" -> <|"foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 6|>|>;
data2DS = data2 // Dataset;
data2DS [All, "foo"] (* <- returns a dataset with 1,3,5 *)
```

**Update**

Some timing comparisons

```
(* make dataset to test *)
colHeader = CharacterRange["a", "z"];
colHeader[[1]] = "letter";
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100000, 26}];
table = Insert[data, colHeader, 1];
dataDS = Dataset[AssociationThread[table[[1]], #] & /@ table[[2 ;;]]];
```

Anton Antonov answer

```
f[ds_Dataset, ch_] := Dataset@Association@Normal@ds[All, #[ch] -> KeyDrop[#, ch] &]
fAns = f[dataDS, "letter"]; // RepeatedTiming (* 0.934 *)
```

kglr answer

```
f0 = GroupBy[##, Association@*KeyDrop[#2]] &;
f0ans = f0[dataDS, "letter"]; // RepeatedTiming (* 1.85 *)

f1 = #[GroupBy[#2] /* Map[Association@*KeyDrop[#2]]] &;
f1ans = f1[dataDS, "letter"]; // RepeatedTiming (* 1.714 *)
```

Sjoerd Smit answer

```
groupByKey[ds_, key_String] := GroupBy[ds, Function[Slot[key]] -> KeyDrop[key], First];
groupByKeyAns = groupByKey[dataDS, "letter"]; // RepeatedTiming (* 1.2 *)
```

*some other timings that don't produce an answer but help to put the times above into context*

```
GroupBy[dataDS, "letter"]; // RepeatedTiming (* 0.25 *)
Dataset[Normal[dataDS]]; // RepeatedTiming (* 0.38 *)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data = {<|"letter" -> "a", "foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2|>, <|
    "letter" -> "b", "foo" -> 3, "bar" -> 4|>, <|"letter" -> "c", 
    "foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 6|>};
dataDS = Dataset[data];

ClearAll[f];
f[ds_Dataset, ch_] := ds[Apply[Association], #[ch] -> KeyDrop[#, ch] &];

f[dataDS, "letter"]
```

[image]

(Using the definition suggested by @WReach in the comments.)

### First answer

```
data = {<|"letter" -> "a", "foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2|>, <|
    "letter" -> "b", "foo" -> 3, "bar" -> 4|>, <|"letter" -> "c", 
    "foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 6|>};
dataDS = Dataset[data];

ClearAll[f];
f[ds_Dataset, ch_] := Dataset@Association@Normal@ds[All, #[ch] -> KeyDrop[#, ch] &];

f[dataDS, "letter"]
```

[image]

Comment: +1.  Similarly, `ds[Apply[Association], #[ch] -> KeyDrop[#, ch]&]`

Comment: This appears the fastest answer despite converting to `Normal` and then `Dataset`

Comment: I went with a similiar riff on what Anton did: `f[ds_, col_] := 
 Dataset[AssociationThread[
   Normal@ds[[All, col]] -> Normal[KeyDrop[ds, col]]]]`

Comment: @WReach I updated my answer with your suggestion. (It is also faster.)

Comment: I missed WReach reply initially and will select this as the answer as it does not involve converting back to normal and is the fastest answer.

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability, sounds good.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0 = GroupBy[##, Association @* KeyDrop[#2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
ds = Dataset @ {<|"letter" -> "a", "foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2|>, 
        <|"letter" -> "b", "foo" -> 3, "bar" -> 4|>, 
        <|"letter" -> "c", "foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 6|>};

Row[{ds, f0[ds, "letter"], f0[ds, "foo"], f0[ds, "bar"]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

You can also do:

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1 = #[GroupBy[#2] /* Map[Association @* KeyDrop[#2]]] &;

Row[{ds, f1[ds, "letter"], f1[ds, "foo"], f1[ds, "bar"]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

and

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = #[GroupBy @ #2, All, First @ Normal @ Keys @ KeyDrop @ ##] &;

Row[{ds, f2[ds, "letter"], f2[ds, "foo"], f2[ds, "bar"]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer as it does not convert to Normal followed by Dataset and it also introduced me to the Composition (@*). However, Anton's method appears ~2x quicker

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability, could you post an example that you used for timing comparisons?

Comment: @kglt sure thing

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability This method can be sped up a little with `ds[GroupBy[#, #letter & -> KeyDrop["letter"], First] &]`

Comment: @SjoerdSmit This is elegant, would you be able to submit it as an answer?

Comment: @kglr Hi just wanted to ask, how do you revert back form a grouped dataframe to a normal dataframe. say from `f2[ds, "letter"]` to `ds`

Answer (score 5):

Related to kglr's answer, here's a slight variation:

```
ds = Dataset @ {
    <|"letter" -> "a", "foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2|>, 
    <|"letter" -> "b",  "foo" -> 3, "bar" -> 4|>,
    <|"letter" -> "c", "foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 6|>
};
groupByKey[ds_, key_String] := GroupBy[ds, Function[Slot[key]] -> KeyDrop[key], First];
groupByKey[ds, "letter"]
```

Of course, you have to be confident that the key values you're grouping by is actually unique, otherwise you'll be dropping rows.

Comment: Though slightly slower than Anton's answer I found this most helpful as it kept in between the operations within the "Dataset space", i.e. without reverting to Normal and Association.

Answer (score 3):

```
AssociationThread[data[[;; , 1]] -> data[[;; , 2 ;;]]] // Dataset
```

[image]

```
AssociationThread[data[[All, "foo"]] -> KeyDrop["foo"] /@ data] // Dataset
```

[image]